# int(variable.entry.get) returning PY_VAR0 when using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write some code with Tkinter. I am currently trying to create a variable that uses the value of an entry (ttk.Entry), but whenever I try to convert that value into an integer, the value becomes `PY_VAR0`. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from fractions import Fraction
import time

def fracalculator():

def fracalculate():
        fracdec.set(int(numfrac.entry.get) / int(denfrac.entry.get()))
        fracper.set((int(numfrac.entry.get) / int(denfrac.entry.get()))*100)
        print(fracdec)
        print(fracper)
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Your results:").grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=W)
        ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=numfrac).grid(column=1, row=9, sticky=W)
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="/").grid(column=1, row=9)
        ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=denfrac).grid(column=1, row=9, sticky=E)
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="=").grid(column=2, row=9, sticky=W)
        ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=fracdec).grid(column=2, row=9)
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="=").grid(column=2, row=9, sticky=E)
        ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=fracper).grid(column=3, row=9)


numfrac = IntVar()
denfrac = IntVar()
null = StringVar()
null2 = StringVar()
null3 = StringVar()
root.withdraw()
fracalc = tkinter.Tk()
fracalc.title("SuperCalculator")
mainframe = ttk.Frame(fracalc, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Numerator (Top)").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W))
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Denominator (Bottom)").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W))
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=null).grid(column=2, row=2)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=null2).grid(column=2, row=4)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=null3).grid(column=2, row=6)
numfrac.entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=numfrac)
numfrac.entry.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=(E))
denfrac.entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=denfrac)
denfrac.entry.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=(E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate!", command=fracalculate).grid(column=2, row=5)


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("SuperCalculator")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

fracdec = StringVar()
fracper = StringVar()

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Welcome to SuperCalculator!").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Start with a Fraction", 
command=fracalculator).grid(column=1, row=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things.

1. `def fracalculator():` does not have anything inside of it so the rest of the code will probably throw an error. I just put `pass` inside it to test your code.
2. you need to move your `root = tkinter.Tk()` somewhere at the top. It should not be past anything that is referring to root and in your case there is `root.withdraw()` before it and this will cause an error.
3. maybe I don't understand why you are using:

`fracdec.set(int(numfrac.entry.get) / int(denfrac.entry.get()))`
`fracper.set((int(numfrac.entry.get) / int(denfrac.entry.get()))*100)`

but I would use:

```
fracdec = int(numfracentry.get()) / int(denfracentry.get())
fracper = int(numfracentry.get()) / (int(denfracentry.get())*100)
```

4. as for the `PY_VAR0` thing. I believe it is in reference to the tkinter.intVar object. You should use `.get()` to get the value of the intVar object.

try using this instead

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from fractions import Fraction
import time

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("SuperCalculator")

def fracalculator():
    pass

def fracalculate():
    fracdec = int(numfrac.entry.get()) / int(denfrac.entry.get())
    fracper = int(numfrac.entry.get()) / (int(denfrac.entry.get())*100)
    print(fracdec)
    print(fracper)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Your results:").grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=numfrac).grid(column=1, row=9, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="/").grid(column=1, row=9)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=denfrac).grid(column=1, row=9, sticky=E)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="=").grid(column=2, row=9, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=fracdec).grid(column=2, row=9)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="=").grid(column=2, row=9, sticky=E)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=fracper).grid(column=3, row=9)

numfrac = IntVar()
denfrac = IntVar()
null = StringVar()
null2 = StringVar()
null3 = StringVar()
root.withdraw()
fracalc = tkinter.Tk()
fracalc.title("SuperCalculator")
mainframe = ttk.Frame(fracalc, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Numerator (Top)").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W))
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Denominator (Bottom)").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W))
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=null).grid(column=2, row=2)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=null2).grid(column=2, row=4)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=null3).grid(column=2, row=6)
numfrac.entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=numfrac)
numfrac.entry.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=(E))
denfrac.entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=denfrac)
denfrac.entry.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=(E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate!", command=fracalculate).grid(column=2, row=5)

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

fracdec = StringVar()
fracper = StringVar()

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Welcome to SuperCalculator!").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Start with a Fraction", 
command=fracalculator).grid(column=1, row=3)

root.mainloop()
```